# numerical integration of multivariable functions

Tags: r, function, plot, numeric, numerical-integration

Hi I am stuck with numerical integration of a function. I have this function:

```
Nd_f <- function(a,t) {
theta(t-a)*exp(-l*(1-exp(-a))) }
```

which is used in another function defined below:

```
Nd <- function(s) {
integrate(Nd_f, lower = 0, upper = s, t=s)$value }
```

where, theta() is a known function. So, using these functions I can evaluate Nd(t). But when I try to plot it using:

```
plot(Nd(0:500), log="y")
```

I get the following error:

> Error in integrate(Nd_theta, lower = 0, upper = s, t = s) : 
>     evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length

I don't understand if I can evaluate it for all the values of t, why I cant plot it?

l=0.025, v= 0.001 and

```
theta <- function(t) { exp(-v*t) }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming `theta = exp` and `l = r = 1`, so:

```
Nd_f <- function(a,t) exp(t-a)*exp(-(1-exp(-r*a)))
```

---

Function `Nd <- function(s) integrate(Nd_f, lower = 0, upper = s, t=s)$value` aims to evaluate the integral:

[image]

Note that `integrate` is not a vectorized function. **A vectorized function can take vector input, and return a vector.** For example, the `exp` function is vectorized, because:

```
exp(1:3)
# [1]  2.718282  7.389056 20.085537
```

**But `integrate` is not. You are only allowed to pass in a scalar for `lower` and `upper`.** So, there is no problem if you do:

```
Nd(1)
# [1] 1.273614
```

but it does not work when you do:

```
Nd(1:2)
# [1] 2.286086
# There were 15 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 15)
# warnings()
# Warning messages:
# 1: In t - a : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

**You need to wrap up your scalar function `Nd` to get a vectorized function.** If you are really new to R, you might use a `for` loop:

```
Nd_vectorized_for <- function(s) {
  result <- numeric(length(s))
  for (i in 1:length(s)) {
    result[i] <- Nd(s[i])
    }
  result  ## or `return(result)`
  }
```

Now this function can take vector input and return a vector:

```
Nd_vectorized_for(1:2)
# [1] 1.273614 4.276839
```

People more experienced with R will suggest replacing `for` loop with `*apply` family function (read `?sapply` to see this family):

```
Nd_vectorized_sapply <- function(s) sapply(s, Nd)

Nd_vectorized_sapply(1:2)
# [1] 1.273614 4.276839
```

But `integrate` is not a cheap operation, so there is no performance gain from `sapply`:

```
system.time(Nd_vectorized_for(sample(1:10,100000,replace=TRUE)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  6.256   0.004   6.268 
system.time(Nd_vectorized_sapply(sample(1:10,100000,replace=TRUE)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  6.200   0.004   6.212
```

With a vectorized function, you can produce the plot you want:

```
plot(Nd_vectorized_for(1:50), log = "y")
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you use `Vectorize` i.e. `Vectorize(Nd)(1:2)
#[1] 1.273614 4.276839`

Comment: It is from experience.

Comment: @akrun This was helpful, especially for multivariable arguments integration. Thanks!